# Populating NumPy array with most performance

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matrix

I want to populate a matrix by function `f()` which consumes arrays `a`, `b`, `c` and `d`:

[image]

A nested loop is possible but I'm looking for a faster way. I tried `np.fromfunction` with no luck. Function f has a conditional so the solution should preferably support conditionals. Example function:

```
def f(a,b,c,c):
    return a+b+c+d if a==b else a*b*c*d
```

How `np.fromfunction` failed:

```
>>> a = np.array([1,2,3,4,5])
>>> b = np.array([10,20,30])
>>> def f(i,j): return a[i] * b[j]
>>> np.fromfunction(f, (3,5))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\numeric.py", line 1853, in fromfunction
    return function(*args, **kwargs)
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in fun
IndexError: arrays used as indices must be of integer (or boolean) type
```

Comment: Without more details about the function, it's going to be hard to suggest the correct approach. With the information you've given, `fromfunction` or nested loops seems the best way. What did you try that you say you had no luck with?

Comment: I've added an example function if it helps. The reason I had no luck with fromfunction is because the indices are already broadcasted which cannot be used to pick values from 1d arrays . why this fails is shown above

Comment: An `if` condition could be vectorized so you don't need a call to `fromfunction`, which would have to call your `function` for every index. The `fromfunction` that failed includes an indexing operation. Is this a part of the function you actually want? Your example could be recreated _without_ `fromfunction` by adding an axis to `b` and broadcasting: `b[:, None] * a` gives you the 3x5 array where the `(i, j)` element is a multiplication of `a[j]` and `b[i]`

Comment: Also your first `fun` doesn't really make sense: do you want to return the sum (or product) of the _indices_ (which is what `a`, `b` `c`, `d`) are, or do you want to return the _values_ at those indices in the arrays? Did you mean `def fun(i, j): return a[i]+b[i]+c[i]+d[j] if i==j else a[i]*b[i]*c[i]*d[j]`

Comment: I've added an answer, but I could edit it if you [edit] your question to include more specifics about your requirements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason the function fails is that `np.fromfunction` passes floating-point values, which are not valid as indices. You can modify your function like this to make it work:

```py
def fun(i,j):
  return a[j.astype(int)] * b[i.astype(int)]

print(np.fromfunction(fun, (3,5)))
```

```
[[ 10  20  30  40  50]
 [ 20  40  60  80 100]
 [ 30  60  90 120 150]]
```

Answer (score 1):

Jake has explained why your `fromfunction` approach fails. However, you don't need `fromfunction` for your example. You could simply add an axis to `b` and have numpy broadcast the shapes:

```
a = np.array([1,2,3,4,5])
b = np.array([10,20,30])
def fun(i,j): return a[j.astype(int)] * b[i.astype(int)]

f1 = np.fromfunction(fun, (3, 5))
f2 = b[:, None] * a

(f1 == f2).all() # True
```

Extending this to the function you showed that contains an `if` condition, you could just split the `if` into two operations in sequence: creating an array given by the `if` expression, and overwriting the relevant parts by the `else` expression.

```
a = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
b = np.array([5, 4, 3, 2, 1])
c = np.array([100, 200, 300, 400, 500])

d = np.array([0, 1, 2, 3])

# Calculate the values at all indices as the product
result = d[:, None] * (a * b * c)
# array([[   0,    0,    0,    0,    0],
#        [ 500, 1600, 2700, 3200, 2500],
#        [1000, 3200, 5400, 6400, 5000],
#        [1500, 4800, 8100, 9600, 7500]])

# Calculate sum 
sum_arr = d[:, None] + (a + b + c)
# array([[106, 206, 306, 406, 506],
#        [107, 207, 307, 407, 507],
#        [108, 208, 308, 408, 508],
#        [109, 209, 309, 409, 509]])

# Set diagonal elements (i==j) to sum:
np.fill_diagonal(result, np.diag(sum_arr))
```

which gives the following `result`:

```
array([[ 106,    0,    0,    0,    0],
       [ 500,  207, 2700, 3200, 2500],
       [1000, 3200,  308, 6400, 5000],
       [1500, 4800, 8100,  409, 7500]])
```

Comment: Thanks very much for looking at it and providing an answer Pranav. Really appreciated :)